# What is the difference between Subscription imports

Tags: rxjs

What is the difference between:

`import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';`

and

`import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';`

It seems both will compile fine without issues.  Is one way more correct than the other? Are there any issues to using either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same. Using `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';` the Subscription gets imported from the [index.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/730424e80776bb89f971def4d87f9d7273c459cc/src/index.ts#L24) [barrel file](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel) and using `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';` the Subscription gets imported from the its own file. If you look into the index.ts you can see that exports it `export { Subscription } from './internal/Subscription';`